# How to close the modal window by clicking on the cross icon?

Tags: wordpress, modal-dialog

I have modal window. but doesn't get vanished if I click on the cross button. How to solve the issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#close').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('#Model').hide()
});
```

Replace ID or class of the button in '#close' and replace '#Model' with pop div class or ID

Comment: i think the op will need a whole tutorial on this, they are obviously not going to learn js or programming in general,  but good answer !